RS-232 transfer speed above standard or under standard - how to
I've been trying to analyze how do certain parameters of serial communication (for instance parity, flow control etc.) affect the real transfer speed of RS-232. However, I'm not sure how to judge whether the real speed in the current situation is above or under expectancy.
Let's say we have two measurements. One transfers a binary file of 0's using YMODEM with a Baud Rate of 19 200 b/s and the other tranfers the same file using Kermit with Baud Rate 115 200 b/s. The first situation reached a real transfer speed of 17 720 b/s and the one with Kermit reached 420 000 b/s. My question is - if the real speed goes below or over the baud rate, does it confirm that speed really depends on the communication protocol for good or worse? Also what I mean by baud rate is the choice "Bits per second" in HyperTerminal emulation program.
What I want to make is a table full of "Over the standard" or "Under the standard" instead of speed values so that I can use a chi-squared test on the results to confirm their independence or dependence.
Thanks in advance.
I've already tried to add a cell to my table of measurements that writes "Over the standard" if the real speed goes over atleast 90 % of the Baud Rate (since speed has a tendency of being quite unstable sometimes) and in other case it writes "Under the standard". However, using a chi-squared test on this approach actually proved to me that transfer speed shouldn't depend on parity although I was expecting to prove that using parity actually decreases the real speed value.

The baudrate is the actual rate that bits are transmitted over the wire within a UART character/byte frame. However frames need not be continuously sent, hence the asynchronous designation. So the actual transfer rate of UART frames can be less than the baudrate. Even worse, the throughput for the payload (i.e. your data) will always be less because of UART framing overhead (typically two of ten bits or 20%). Your examples of "real speed" therefore make no sense, especially with such contrived data and unspecified versions of protocols.
